Follow changes with the mouse cursor when pressing ctrl + z/Z (undo/redo) in JupyterLab
In most of the text editors that I used (e.g., Notepad++), the mouse cursor follows the positions of the changes when undoing/redoing text pieces. Is there a way to have this effect in JupyterLab, as well? It's quite uncomfortable that I cannot see the last change during these textual manipulations.

I feel the pain too. This is tracked in https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_ydoc/issues/240 and https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/15102
